# VLC no sound after Pause

Tags: vlc

I am using VLC 2.0.5, It fails to produce sound after i press pause the video. It gets back after changing the audio settings or restarting the video

Comment: Related: [How do I fix VLC sound studdering after pause/resume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457272)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had the same (annoying) problem. You have to manually change your audio-device settings in VLC's preferences. See the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

To find your sound-card, use the following command in the terminal.

```
sudo aplay -l
```

Comment: Restart VLC after making these changes.

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 22.04.1 and VLC 3.0.16.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: vlc would lose audio after seeking forward or back, on Kubuntu 14. I changed Preferences (Simple) -> Audio -> Output Module to Alsa & Output Device to 'Playback/recording through PulseAudio server'.

Selecting the same options in Preferences (All) didn't work. Go figure.

You need to close & reopen vlc for changes to take effect.